# Folders/files not updated to Github?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm still very new to all these so please be patient with me.
I've recently changed my GitHub username and that is when I started noticing this issue: files or folders that are manually created on VS code or in the windows folder don't get uploaded onto GitHub. Whenever I try git add. & commit commands, I get this error message below:

```
warning: could not open directory '.vscode/': Permission denied
```

However, if I create a file on GitHub itself, say an index HTML file, it shows up on my windows folder. I can push any changes to this HTML file made on VS code and it shows up GitHub.

I have provided the log below if it's of any help.

```sh
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Using git 2.27.0.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
> git rev-parse --git-dir
Open repository: c:\Users\raeye\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\raeyean\code\raeleneho\todoapp
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse main
> git config --global user.email
> git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right main...refs/remotes/origin/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git show --textconv :html/todoList.html
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\raeye\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\raeyean\code\raeleneho\todoapp\html\todoList.html
> git show --textconv :.vscode/settings.json
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\raeye\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\raeyean\code\raeleneho\todoapp\.vscode\settings.json
> git show --textconv :html/todoList.html
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\raeye\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\raeyean\code\raeleneho\todoapp\html\todoList.html
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse main
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right main...refs/remotes/origin/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse main
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right main...refs/remotes/origin/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\raeye\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\raeyean\code\raeleneho\todoapp\html\todoList.html
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git show --textconv :html/todoList.html
> git rev-parse main
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right main...refs/remotes/origin/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git init
error: could not write config file C:/Users/raeye/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs/home/raeyean/code/raeleneho/todoapp/.git/config: Permission denied
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'
> git status -z -u
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\raeye\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\raeyean\code\raeleneho\todoapp\html\todoList.html
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse main
> git show --textconv :html/todoList.html
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right main...refs/remotes/origin/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git status -z -u
> git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\raeye\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\raeyean\code\raeleneho\todoapp\html\todoList.html
> git show --textconv :html/todoList.html
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse main
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name main@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right main...refs/remotes/origin/main
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can fetch but not push, that means your repository is a public one, but your `git config credential.helper`, probably set to `manager` (even in your WSL2 Ubuntu session), has cached the wrong credential.

Try and type:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin https://<myNewGitHubAccount>@github.com/<myNewGitHubAccount>/myRepo
```

Then try and push again: a popup should ask for your GitHub Account password (or better yet, for a [PAT -- Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token))

If you go the SSH route, make sure to follow "[Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)
", and check if `ssh -Tv git@github.com` does end up with a welcome message.

Comment: Hi VonC, thanks for the reply.
I typed cd /path/to/repo into the terminal and this was the error message I got:
cd: no such file or directory: /path/to/repo
Is this what I should be expecting?

Comment: @rae This is meant to be adapted to your particular environment: please replace "path/to/your/repository" by the *actual* path you are using locally.

Comment: Ok got it. I tried the next command you suggested using HTTP and even SSH, no pop up requesting for Gtihub Acount password.

➜  todoapp git:(main) git remote set-url origin https://github.com/raeleneho/todoapp
➜  todoapp git:(main) git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/raeleneho/todoapp (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/raeleneho/todoapp (push)
➜  todoapp git:(main) git remote set-url origin git@github.com:raeleneho/todoapp.git
➜  todoapp git:(main) git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:raeleneho/todoapp.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:raeleneho/todoapp.git (push)

Comment: @rae You are supposed to replace `<myNewGitHubAccount>` by your new GitHub account name: `git remote set-url origin https://raeleneho@github.com/raeleneho/todoapp`. SSH would not trigger any popup, since the credential.helper is only for caching HTTPS credentials (username/password)

Comment: Hi @VonC, thanks for clarifying. I tried that, didn't get a pop-up either. 
➜  todoapp git:(main) git remote set-url origin [link]https://raeleneho@github.com/raeleneho/todoapp
➜  todoapp git:(main) git remote -v
origin  [link]https://raeleneho@github.com/raeleneho/todoapp (fetch)
origin  [link]https://raeleneho@github.com/raeleneho/todoapp (push)

Comment: @rae Great. What did you get as a result? Are you using HTTPS or SSH. If HTTPS, does `git config credential.helper` is set to manager? If you still have the issue, can you upgrade to Git 2.29.1? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: I used HTTPs. Completed my Git update to Git 2.29.0. Checked credential helper- manager. Still unable to git add. and getting the same error message. 
➜  / cd home/raeyean/code/raeleneho/todoapp
➜  todoapp git:(main) git version
git version 2.29.0
➜  todoapp git:(main) git config --global credential.helper                                                                      
manager
➜  todoapp git:(main) git add .
warning: could not open directory '.vscode/': Permission denied

Comment: @rae Are you in a WSL2 Ubuntu session? Or do you have the same issue in a regular CMD session?